# How to solve the error "Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve"?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

Here I want to solve the partial differential equations

```
NDSolve[{\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ox\),
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[\[Tau], t] == -0.0732601 Ox[\[Tau], t] + 
    9.34208 Ox[0, t] Oz[\[Tau], t] + I (1 - \[Tau]^2) 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Oy\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[\[Tau], t], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Oy\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[\[Tau], t] == -0.0732601 Oy[\[Tau], t] + 
    9.34208 Oy[0, t] Oz[\[Tau], t] - I (1 - \[Tau]^2) 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Ox\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[\[Tau], t], 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(Oz\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[\[Tau], 
    t] == ((0. + 0.195 I) (E^((0. + 5560.54 I) ArcTanh[\[Tau]]) - 
       1. E^((0. + 5560.7 I) ArcTanh[\[Tau]])))/ArcTanh[\[Tau]] - 
    9.34208 (Ox[0, t] Ox[\[Tau], t] + Oy[0, t] Oy[\[Tau], t]) - 
    0.0765116 Oz[\[Tau], t], 
  Ox[\[Tau], 
    0] == ((0. + 1.35143 I) (E^((0. + 5560.54 I) ArcTanh[\[Tau]]) - 
      1. E^((0. + 5560.7 I) ArcTanh[\[Tau]])))/ArcTanh[\[Tau]], 
  Oy[\[Tau], 0] == 0., 
  Oz[\[Tau], 
    0] == ((0. + 6.35796 I) (E^((0. + 5560.54 I) ArcTanh[\[Tau]]) - 
      1. E^((0. + 5560.7 I) ArcTanh[\[Tau]])))/ArcTanh[\[Tau]], 
  Ox[1, t] == 0, Oy[1, t] == 0, Oz[1, t] == 0, Ox[-1, t] == 0, 
  Oy[-1, t] == 0, Oz[-1, t] == 0}, {Ox[\[Tau], t], Oy[\[Tau], t], 
  Oz[\[Tau], t]}, {\[Tau], -1, 1}, {t, 0, 1800}]
```

And the error is given as `NDSolve::delpde: Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve.`

How to solve this?

Comment: I think this happens because of  `Ox[0, t]` and `Oy[0, t]`. Mathematica thinks the first variable is time and therefore the error. What happens if you switch $\tau$ and $t$ in every function?

Comment: Thank you @mattiav27. However, if switch `Ox[\[Tau], t]` to `Ox[t, \[Tau]]`, the physical meaning will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This system can be solved with using method of lines. For this we introduce discrete variable `grid` instead of $\tau$ and differentiation matrix `dm` instead of $\partial_{\tau}$ as follows

```
ff={-0.0732601*Ox[\[Tau], t] + 9.34208*Ox[0, t]*Oz[\[Tau], t] + I*(1 - \[Tau]^2)*Derivative[1, 0][Oy][\[Tau], t], 
   -.0732601*Oy[\[Tau], t] + 9.34208*Oy[0, t]*Oz[\[Tau], t] - I*(1 - \[Tau]^2)*Derivative[1, 0][Ox][\[Tau], t], 
   ((0. + 0.195*I)*(E^((0. + 5560.54*I)*ArcTanh[\[Tau]]) - 1.*E^((0. + 5560.7*I)*ArcTanh[\[Tau]])))/ArcTanh[\[Tau]] - 
     9.34208*(Ox[0, t]*Ox[\[Tau], t] + Oy[0, t]*Oy[\[Tau], t]) - 0.0765116*Oz[\[Tau], t]}; 
  

bc = {Ox[\[Tau], 
    0] == ((0. + 1.35143*I)*(E^((0. + 5560.54*I)*ArcTanh[\[Tau]]) - 
        1.*E^((0. + 5560.7*I)*ArcTanh[\[Tau]])))/ArcTanh[\[Tau]], 
  Oy[\[Tau], 0] == 0., 
     Oz[\[Tau], 
    0] == ((0. + 6.35796*I)*(E^((0. + 5560.54*I)*ArcTanh[\[Tau]]) - 
        1.*E^((0. + 5560.7*I)*ArcTanh[\[Tau]])))/ArcTanh[\[Tau]], 
  Ox[1, t] == 0, 
     Oy[1, t] == 0, Oz[1, t] == 0, Ox[-1, t] == 0, Oy[-1, t] == 0, 
  Oz[-1, t] == 0}; {Ox[\[Tau], t], Oy[\[Tau], t], Oz[\[Tau], t]};

nn = 10; h = 1/nn; grid = Range[-1, 1, h];M = Length[grid]; 
eps = $MachineEpsilon; 
ox[t_] = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]][t], {i, M}]; 
oy[t_] = Table[Symbol["y" <> ToString[i]][t], {i, M}]; 
oz[t_] = Table[Symbol["z" <> ToString[i]][t], {i, M}];
fddf1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], grid, 
  DifferenceOrder -> 2]; dm = fddf1@"DifferentiationMatrix";
f = ff /. {Derivative[1, 0][Ox][\[Tau], t] -> dm . ox[t], 
   Derivative[1, 0][Oy][\[Tau], t] -> dm . oy[t], 
   Derivative[1, 0][Oz][\[Tau], t] -> dm . oz[t], 
   Ox[\[Tau], t] -> ox[t], Oy[\[Tau], t] -> oy[t], 
   Oz[\[Tau], t] -> oz[t], Ox[0, t] -> ox[t][[nn + 1]], 
   Oy[0, t] -> oy[t][[nn + 1]], 
   Oz[0, t] -> 
    oz[t][[nn + 1]]}; con = {Derivative[1, 0][Ox][\[Tau], 
     t] -> (dm . ox[t])[[i]], 
   Derivative[1, 0][Oy][\[Tau], t] -> (dm . oy[t])[[i]], 
   Derivative[1, 0][Oz][\[Tau], t] -> (dm . oz[t])[[i]], 
   Ox[\[Tau], t] -> ox[t][[i]], Oy[\[Tau], t] -> oy[t][[i]], 
   Oz[\[Tau], t] -> oz[t][[i]], Ox[0, t] -> ox[t][[nn + 1]], 
   Oy[0, t] -> oy[t][[nn + 1]], Oz[0, t] -> oz[t][[nn + 1]]} // Quiet;

sys1 = Table[
  D[ox[t][[i]], t] == ff[[1]] /. con /. {\[Tau] -> grid[[i]] + eps, 
    ox[t][[1]] -> 0, ox[t][[-1]] -> 0, oy[t][[1]] -> 0, 
    oy[t][[-1]] -> 0, oz[t][[1]] -> 0, oz[t][[-1]] -> 0}, {i, 2, 
   M - 1}]; sys2 = 
 Table[D[oy[t][[i]], t] == ff[[2]] /. 
    con /. {\[Tau] -> grid[[i]] + eps, ox[t][[1]] -> 0, 
    ox[t][[-1]] -> 0, oy[t][[1]] -> 0, oy[t][[-1]] -> 0, 
    oz[t][[1]] -> 0, oz[t][[-1]] -> 0}, {i, 2, M - 1}]; sys3 = 
 Table[D[oz[t][[i]], t] == ff[[3]] /. 
    con /. {\[Tau] -> grid[[i]] + eps, ox[t][[1]] -> 0, 
    ox[t][[-1]] -> 0, oy[t][[1]] -> 0, oy[t][[-1]] -> 0, 
    oz[t][[1]] -> 0, oz[t][[-1]] -> 0}, {i, 2, M - 1}];

bc1 = Table[
  ox[0][[i]] == bc[[1, 2]] /. {\[Tau] -> grid[[i]] + eps}, {i, 2, 
   M - 1}]; bc2 = 
 Table[oy[0][[i]] == bc[[2, 2]] /. {\[Tau] -> grid[[i]] + eps}, {i, 2,
    M - 1}]; bc3 = 
 Table[oz[0][[i]] == bc[[3, 2]] /. {\[Tau] -> grid[[i]] + eps}, {i, 2,
    M - 1}];
X[t_] = Join[Drop[Drop[ox[t], 1], -1], Drop[Drop[oy[t], 1], -1], 
   Drop[Drop[oz[t], 1], -1]];
```

Solution with using `NDSolve`

```
sol = NDSolve[{sys1, sys2, sys3, bc1, bc2, bc3}, X[t], {t, 0, 10}];
```

Visualization

```
Table[Plot[ReIm[ox[t][[i]] /. sol[[1]]] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> i, PlotRange -> All], {i, 2, M - 1}]

Table[Plot[ReIm[oy[t][[i]] /. sol[[1]]] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> i, PlotRange -> All], {i, 2, M - 1}]

Table[Plot[ReIm[oz[t][[i]] /. sol[[1]]] // Evaluate, {t, 0, 10}, 
  Frame -> True, PlotLabel -> i, PlotRange -> All], {i, 2, M - 1}]
```

[image: Figure 1]