# How to solve a delay partial differential equations numerically？

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

A set of special partial diffential euqations like this:

$$\dot{O}_x=\textrm{i}\cos^2(\tau)\partial_\tau O_y+\alpha O_x(\tau=0,t)O_z-\frac{O_x}{T_2}$$
$$\dot{O}_y=-\textrm{i}\cos^2(\tau)\partial_\tau O_x+\alpha O_y(\tau=0,t)O_z-\frac{O_y}{T_2}$$
$$\dot{O}_z=-\alpha\left[O_x(\tau=0,t)O_x+O_y(\tau=0,t)O_y\right]-(\frac{1}{T_1}+G)O_z+GP_0\int d\omega\rho(\omega)e^{-\textrm{i} \omega\tan\tau}$$
where $\rho(\omega)$ is a uniform distribution. Namely $\rho(\omega)=1/(\omega_2-\omega_1)$ in $[\omega_1,\omega_2]$ and $\rho(\omega)=0$ otherwise.

Initial state: $\left\{O_x(\tau,t=0),O_y(\tau,t=0),O_z(\tau,t=0)\right\}=\left\{\sin(\pi/15),0,\cos(\pi/15)\right\}$. Other parameters can be set as $\alpha=10,T_1=T_2=15,G=0.03,P_0=1$.

Boundary:$\left\{O_x(\tau=\pm\pi/2,t),O_y(\tau=\pm\pi/2,t),O_z(\tau\pm\pi/2,t)\right\}=\left\{0,0,0\right\}$

Here the term $O_{x,y}(\tau=0,t)$ makes the equations delay. And numerically solving this system is intractable. Anyone can help me? Thank you.

Comment: There a number of distracting things in this post. I would not use capital $O$ to denote an unknown. I would not use $[$ and $]$ as a replacement for parantheses in an equation. Do I understand correctly that $\int d\omega \rho(\omega) e^{-i \tan \tau} = e^{-i \tan \tau}$? (If yes, why do you write the integral? If no, please explain.) It is also distracting that you refer to $\tau = 0$ terms as delay terms, even though the time variable is $t$ (you refer to $t=0$ as initial). Maybe $\tau = 0$ terms are non-local terms, rather than delay terms, but I do not know how you interpret $\tau$.

Comment: What is your approach to this problem? Have you any code?

Comment: You asked 12 questions on this site SE so far, but you never [accepted an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)!?

Comment: @user293787 Sorry, the correct is $\int d\omega \rho(\omega) e^{-i \omega \tan \tau} $. Second, when I use NDsolve in mathematica to solve this system, the error is " Delay partial differential equations are not currently supported by NDSolve". I think this is because  the derivative of the unknown function at $\tau>0$ is given in terms of the values of the function at $\tau=0$.  Although $t$ is the real time, $\tau$ still can be seen as "time" so that this system will be "delayed" by defination.

Comment: Please EDIT your question if there are mistakes. And please consider going back and accepting answers to your old questions. People might be reluctant to answer if you do not respect how this site works.

Comment: @user293787 Thanks for your notice. I am not very familiar with this site, sorry about that.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, Thank you so much. I notice that you answered my previous question. Actaully, these questions are the same. Because the previous one is not very clear, so I ask agin here. Unfortunately, the method you provided is pretty but gives the wrong answer. I don‘t know why.

Comment: Re "when I use NDsolve in mathematica to solve this system" Post your **code** in a copy and paste-able form (`InputForm`) so that others can copy and paste it into a notebook.

Comment: @so_sure Could you reproduce solution with my method? I see the difference with the previous post on  https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/274034/how-to-solve-the-error-delay-partial-differential-equations-are-not-currently-s/274115#274115